# Create random number excluding numbers in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

So let's say I have a list of numbers (not a specific range, which could change), and want to generate a random number which excludes the numbers in the list.

List of excluded numbers comes from a sql query.

and the only limit for the random number is the number of digits, which can come from:

```
random_number = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

so I want to generate the random number (with size limit) excluding a list of numbers.

```
while random_number in exclude_list:
    random_number = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(size))
```

Is there a pythonic way (other than using while loop) to do that?

example: generate a 2digit random number which does not exist in a list of numbers like exclude_list=[22,34,56,78]

Comment: How big is the list of excluded numbers? How big is the list of included numbers?

Comment: list of excluded numbers comes from a sql query, so not a fixed length.

Comment: I think you need bounds to include too, having a random number from `-infinity` to `+infinity` except for ones in your list would be difficult.

Comment: You'll stand a better chance of getting useful responses if you show you've put some effort into solving the problem yourself first. If you have, please add what you've tried to the question.

Comment: Your edit confused me even more. What is the range from which you want to generate random number? By exclude list due you mean number in the list should be generated as the random number OR the digits in the exclude list should not be the part of randomly generated number?

Comment: As mentioned, the only limit is the size of the digit for the random number (so let's say I want to generate a 2 digit random number which doe NOT exist in a list of numbers like exclude=[22,23,56,78])

Answer (score 6):

You may call the `random.choice` using `set` to exclude the items in list you do not want to be the part of random selection:

```
>>> import random

>>> my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> exclude_list = [3, 6, 7]

# list containing elements from `my_list` excluding those of `exclude_list`
>>> valid_list = list(set(my_list) - set(exclude_list))

>>> random.choice(valid_list)
5  # valid random number
```